# BigQuery: EACH still required thought deprecated according to release notes

Tags: google-bigquery

I still get errors of the form:

> Error: 4.1 - 4.97: The JOIN operator's right-side table must be a
>   small table. Switch the tables if the left-side table is smaller, or
>   use JOIN EACH if both tables are larger than the maximum described at
>   http://goo.gl/wXqgHs.

if I try to use a simple JOIN.

The EACH keyword was supposed to have been deprecated on August 25th (https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/release-notes?hl=en#08252015). Has the roll-out of this been delayed?

I'll attempt to clarify where my confusion comes from:

This blog entry http://googlecloudplatform.blogspot.com/2015/08/Google-BigQuery-adds-UDF-support-for-deeper-cloud-analytics.html indicated that EACH was no longer required

> Dynamic query optimization. Improves reliability and performance for
>   complex queries such as large JOIN or GROUP BY operations.  You can
>   expect to see your project activated in the coming weeks.  Users will
>   no longer need to specify the EACH keyword, which greatly simplifies
>   the writing of queries, particularly for applications that
>   programmatically generate SQL such as visualization tools and
>   dashboards

And it is no longer mentioned in the Query Reference https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/query-reference

Comment: I've been wondering about this as well. I would be very happy if this were indeed deprecated, since I've never understood the point of asking users the equivalent of "Are you _sure_ you want to see those results? You have to add the magic word!"

Comment: I try to explain it here https://youtu.be/7XyfcDMU8kA?t=1573

Comment: Well, could you give us the gist of it here? The only reason I can come up with is that it is costly for Google so they would rather not have us use it unless we really need it.

Answer (score 1):

Most probably your query has something large, or a big join explosion, check your ON conditions to verify if you have not missed a restrictive clause there.

Otherwise the error message has not been updated, and that's why it tells you to use EACH, but the `EACH` keyboard has been deprecated. So only the error message is vague here, not the use of EACH keyword.

You can post the query in order to improve it.

Comment: The error relates to the right-hand-side table being large. EACH has always been required in these cases but is not supposed to be necessary any more.

Comment: Note that 'EACH' is still required in some cases. It has to go away, but there are still use cases that are only solvable with EACH.

Comment: @FelipeHoffa. I'm confused. The blog entry referenced seemed to indicate that EACH is no longer required and it is no longer mentioned in the Query Reference (see above). Were the reports of EACH's demise premature?